# Why is viewForAnnotation unnecessarily fired many times when scrolling the mkmapview in the simulator?

Tags: xcode, scroll, mkmapview, zooming, mkannotationview

I put 128 pins on the mkmapview. Once I zoom in on the map with either double clicking the map or using the slider that I put in, and then scroll the map once or twice, the map scrolls by itself for a while and the zooms out by itself and then stops.  During the time, the following methods are fired in order.

```
regionDidChangeAnimated
viewForAnnotation  - several times fired in succession
didAddAnnotionViews
viewForAnnotation  - 30 to 40 times fired in succession
didAddAnnotionViews
regionDidChangeAnimated
regionDidChangeAnimated
```

The sequence of methods fired and frequency varies depending on the scrolling action.
Could someone please give a clue why this is happening and scrolling by itself for a while and zooming out by itself and then stopping?

Thank you very much.

The relevant codes are as follows.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    for (XMLItem *item in [post items]) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
        theCoordinate.latitude = [[item latitude] floatValue];
        theCoordinate.longitude = [[item longitude] floatValue];
        MapAnnotation *mapAnn = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init];
        mapAnn.coordinate = theCoordinate;
        mapAnn.title = [item landmark];
        mapAnn.subtitle = [item title];
        [mapView addAnnotation:mapAnn];
        [mapAnn release];
    }


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{   
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id<MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate] ,50000,50000);
    [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)zoomSliderChanged
{
    float sliderValue = 7 -[zoomSlider value];
    int spanMeter = (int)powf(10.0, sliderValue) * 5;
    MKCoordinateRegion region1;
    region1.center.latitude = 34.050499;
    region1.center.longitude = -118.255302;
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance (region1.center,                            spanMeter , spanMeter);    
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your code is requesting the map to move in didaddAnnotations etc. Simply don't and move that message elsewhere where it won't be called.

You can also add NSLog to check when these delegate methods are called, when you just move the mapview.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. 

As you suggested, I moved the code in the didAddAnnotationViews method right near the end of the viewDidLoad method, and commented out the didAddAnnotationViews method. And the map does not scroll by itself neither zoom out.

I am a novice,and could you explain the purpose of the didAddAnnotationViews or when to use that method then? 
Thank you very much.